# value cannot be converted to a timestamp (Error in Nifi)

Tags: mysql, etl, apache-nifi, data-warehouse

I have a mysql destination table with column type datetime.

my nifi flow is like convertJsontoSQL -> putsql (into this destination table). The action is delete for putsql.

After conversion of Jsontosql i am getting a value '2023-03-28 15:54:28' which is a valid timestamp.

but the flow is failing with below error:

```
duetoThevalue of the sqlargs. 14.value is '2023-03-28 15:54:28',

which cannot be converted to a timestamp; routing to failure: java.sql.SQLDataException:

The value of the sql.args. 14.value is '2023-03-28 15:54:28',

which cannot be converted to a timestamp

- Caused by: java. text. ParseException: Unparseable date: "2023-03-28 15:54:28"
```

I can able to use the same value "2023-03-28 15:54:28" for manually inserting into a sample datetime column. and can also able to delete a record with where clause as this value.

I could not understand why Nifi is still not able to convert it to timestamp.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try to use varchar type for those columns.

Answer (score 1):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/

Section **Reads Attributes / sql.args.N.format**

> Date, Time and Timestamp formats all support both custom formats or named format ('yyyy-MM-dd','ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME') as specified according to java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter. If not specified, a long value input is expected to be an unix epoch (milli seconds from 1970/1/1), or a string value in **'yyyy-MM-dd'** format for Date, **'HH:mm:ss.SSS'** for Time

so, you need to set attribute `sql.args.14.format = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

as alternative option - try to set `sql.args.14.type = 1` (CHAR) - in this case  conversion will be done on database level.